# How to insert HTML meta tags in the QTextBrowser?

Tags: qt

I need to insert the following **HTML meta tag** to the **QTextBrowser**’s **head tag**:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

If I insert the tag along with my normal HTML content in the QTextBrowser, it is not working.

Because I am reading a huge number of HTML files with Unicode fonts and loading their content into the QTextBrowser, but without that meta tag the Unicode fonts are not showing properly in the QTextBrowser.

I can’t add that meta tag to each individual files too, one thing because they are too many, 16,280 files; another thing because, as I tried with one file, still the Unicode fonts do not show properly in the QTextBrowser.

Comment: How do you get the content of a file into QTextBrowser at the moment?

Comment: I use **QFile** and **QTextStream** to open and store the contents of the files, then I build a custom string using **QString** where I first append my custom HTML meta tag and then the content of the files, then use **setHTML** to populate the **QTextBrowser**.

Comment: Could you please add the full source code from reading a given filename to populating QTextBrowser?

Comment: I put my content reading and populating codes in this thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495855/why-unicode-fonts-are-not-showing-properly-in-the-qtextbrowser-when-unicode-cont) Please kindly help me in that thread.