# Why Unicode fonts are not showing properly in the QTextBrowser when Unicode contents are read from an html file?

Tags: c++, qt, unicode, qtextbrowser

I am reading an **html** file. The file basically contains **Unicode** texts as follows:

```
<b>akko- sati (ā + kruś), akkhāti (ā + khyā), abbahati (ā + bṛh)</b>
```

But the **QTextBrowser** is not interpreting the **Unicode** fonts. So the **QTextBrowser** shows them as follows:

```
akko- sati (Ä + kruÅ›), akkhÄti (Ä + khyÄ), abbahati (Ä + bá¹›h)
```

The **QTextBrowser** is correctly interpreting the **html** tags. But what’s wrong with the **Unicode** fonts?

Following are my codes for reading and populating the Unicode contents:

```
void MainWindow::populateTextBrowser(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    QFile file("Data\\" + index.data().toString() + ".html");
    if (!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)) {
         statusBar()->showMessage("Cannot open file: " + file.fileName());
    }
    QTextStream textStream1(&file);

    QString string = "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' /><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='Data/Accessories/qss.css' />";
    string += textStream1.readAll();

    ui->textBrowser->setHtml(string); 
}
```

However, if I do not read the **Unicode** content from an **html** file but directly type them into the parameter, then only it interprets the **Unicode** fonts. For example, if I do as follows it is fine:

```
ui->textBrowser->setHtml("<b>akko- sati (ā + kruś), akkhāti (ā + khyā), abbahati (ā + bṛh)</b>");
```

How can I read the **Unicode** contents from **html** files and show them in the **QTextBrowser**?

I shall be very thankful if someone shows me the buggy parts in my codes or tells me a better way of solving my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read a binary file into QString but do not tell the program, which bytes correspond to which unicode character, i.e. you don't specify the "encoding" aka. "codec".

To debug your problem, ask `QTextStream` which codes it uses by default:

```
QTextStream textStream1(&file);
qDebug() << textStream1.codec()->name();
```

On my Linux system, that is already "UTF-8" but it might be different on your system. To force QTextStream interpreting the input as UTF-8, use [QTextStream::setCodec](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qtextstream.html#setCodec).

Comment: Thank you so much. Now my problem is solved. I just added `textStream1.setCodec("UTF-8");` after `QTextStream textStream1(&file);`. Thank you so much once again.

Comment: What was the default codec in your case? Are you on Windows?

Comment: I did not check it. But no need. My problem is solved :D . I am on Windows.

Comment: It is about understanding the problem, not about quick-fixing it ;) Anyways, I am happy it works now!