# QTextBrowser not displaying non-english characters

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qtextbrowser

I'm developing a Qt GUI application to parse out a custom windows binary file that stores unicode text using wchar_t (default UTF-16 encoding). I've constructed a `QString` using `QString::fromWcharArray` and passed it to `QTextBrowser::insertPlainText` like this

```
wchar_t *p = ; // pointer to a wchar_t string in the binary file
QString t = QString::fromWCharArray(p);
ui.logBrowser->insertPlainText(t);
```

The displayed text displays ASCII characters correctly, but non-ASCII characters are displayed as a rectangular box instead. I've followed the code in a debugger and `p` points to a valid wchar_t string and the constructed `QString t` is also a valid string matching the wchar_t string. The problem happens when printing it out on a `QTextBrowser`.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495855/why-unicode-fonts-are-not-showing-properly-in-the-qtextbrowser-when-unicode-cont ?

Comment: @rpsml, I checked that before asking. In his case, I think the issue has to do with reading the file with correct encoding. In my case, I'm operating on a memory mapped file and the generate QString actually is correct when checking it under a debugger. Posting it on a QTextBrowser is where the problem is.

Comment: What font are you using? Does the font support the required characters?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld, I didn't think of that, will try it out and let you know. I think you are correct.

Comment: And what happens, if you don't use `wchar_t`?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld, Yes, got it working, thank you very much. Post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all [read documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromWCharArray). So depending on system you will have different encoding `UCS-4` or `UTF-16`! What is the size of `wchar_t`?

Secondly there is alternative API: try [QString::fromUtf16](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromUtf16).

Finally what kind of character are you using? Hebrew/Cyrillic/Japanese/???. Are you sure those characters are supported by font you are using?

Comment: The issue was with the default font not supporting the character set.